# How do I update an empty JSON column?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am currently trying to update the date of birth for a client and at the moment the column is `NULL`.

See code below - this works if the user already has a date of birth but doesn't work if its empty:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE [dbo].[User]
    SET AdditionalFields = JSON_MODIFY(AdditionalFields, '$.dateOfBirth', '1992-12-03')
    WHERE Id = '1'

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'Transaction Committed'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    PRINT 'Transaction Rolled-Back'
END CATCH
```

Can anyone tell me how I can insert a value for "dateOfBirth" e.g. `{"DateOfBirth": "1980-01-01"}`

Comment: Urgh why do you have that horrid error-handling? It's just going to swallow exceptions and instead put out a message which will be ignored by client apps. Instead just allow the exception to bubble up, and the transaction will be rolled back anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` with `{}`, then modify:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[User] 
SET AdditionalFields = JSON_MODIFY(
    COALESCE(AdditionalFields, '{}'),
    '$.dateOfBirth',
    '1992-12-03'
)
WHERE ...
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uWJjUQ0s)